# Confusing configuring of multiple relay nodes, multi host pool and SRV DNS

Tags: stake-pool, pool

When one building Stake Pool with "Future-proof" and scalability in mind it would make sense to make your setup right from the beginning. While there are various guides about pool setup I haven't found any good resource about multi host setup.

```
cardano-cli stake-pool registration-certificate -h
--multi-host-pool-relay STRING
    The stake pool relay's DNS name that corresponds to an SRV DNS record
```

**based on that and multiple sources of community docs I would expect:**

If I have e.g. 3 Relay nodes then I would perform following setup.

```
_cardano._tcp.relays.cardano.example.com. 300 IN SRV 10 5 6000 relay-1.example.com.
_cardano._tcp.relays.cardano.example.com. 300 IN SRV 10 5 6000 relay-2.example.com.
_cardano._tcp.relays.cardano.example.com. 300 IN SRV 10 20 6000 relay-backup.example.com.
relay-1.example.com 200 IN A 1.2.3.4
relay-2.example.com 200 IN A 1.2.3.5
relay-backup.example.com 200 IN A 1.2.3.6
```

**however looking at IOHK `relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io` it seems that is simply  round-robin DNS A records**

```
dig relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io
;; ANSWER SECTION:
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    54.176.152.50
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    13.114.93.89
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    18.133.59.65
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    3.16.84.177
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    3.129.48.231
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    184.72.21.211
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    3.19.78.159
relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io. 288 IN A    3.121.10.14
```

Have I missed some crucial part of documentation about usage of `--multi-host-pool-relay` or is SRV DNS record part misleading and is meant to be used when one assigns multiple relay IP's to singlehostname? e.g.

```
relays.cardano.example.com 300 IN A 1.2.3.4
relays.cardano.example.com 300 IN A 1.2.3.5
relays.cardano.example.com 300 IN A 1.2.3.6
```

Hope here is some big brain who can clarify how is it then right way to setup `relays.cardano.example.com` such than I could easily scale up or down relays when needed in the feature.

Comment: So from a big picture perspective, what are you trying to achieve? In terms of a physical/virtual layer and a logical layer, what is the end goal with this? I am just better trying to wrap my head around the question. Thanks!

Comment: I think OP is trying to figure out if it is possible to use SRV records with cardano node. It is quite handy and should work much better then regular A record with round robin.

Seems SRV records do work, only it seems it is not yet supported officially(1 year old info, though): https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/2517

Comment: @os11k indeed I'm looking for if it is possible to use SRV records with cardano node since there are some comments and references to it e.g. CoinCashew tutorial mentions that SRV Records should be supported for `multi-host-pool-relay` however I haven't found any official info about the implementation and is it supported or not.